# Setting up Archlinux login with greetdm, ReGreet and cage

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

In a fresh archlinux installation, I have installed greetd and ReGreet, so I can use ReGreet to login in arch instead using the tty and then start the Hyprland. Currently I have to login on tty and then type `Hyprland` to get to the window manager.

When a run the following command:

```bash
$ systemctl start greetd.service
```

The systems automatically goes to the login interface. But if I reboot the machine, I have to login on tty first.

The greetd config file:

```
[terminal]
    vt = 1
[default_session]
    command = "cage -s -- regreet"
    user = "greeter"
```

Output of the command `groups greeter`: video greeter

I am not sure if the systemctl command only works on the current session. I am trying to follow the [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Greetd). Am I missing which step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At point 2 'Starting greetd', it instructs you to *enable* `greetd.service`

Try running:

```
systemctl enable greetd.service
```

or

```
systemctl enable --now greetd.service
```

to both enable and start the service if it is not currently running.
The `enable` command will start the service automatically at boot.

Reference:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd